# HTTP 444 (No Response) instead of 404, 403 error pages?

Tags: http, nginx, http-status-code-404, httpresponse

I always use "return 444" in the nginx config to stop crawlers that access my servers directly via IP or via the wrong hostname. It just closes the connection. Perfect.

Now I want to use this response instead of the standard 404.html pages that nginx throws, but I fail at configuring.

```
error_page 500 502 503 504 /custom_50x.html;
```

This works fine, but I can't "return 444" like here:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name "";
    return      444;
}
```

Does anybody know a way to combine these two?

Comment: An interesting approach, given problems with slowloris and similar drip-connection attacks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Redirect request then you can return status code easily:

```
server {
  error_page 500 502 503 504 @blackhole;

  location @blackhole {
    return 444;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have found the `=444` in the `error_page` directive to be unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks @diachedelic, unfortunately the edit is too small to do it. (min. 6 chars)

Comment: @Howard The indentation could be fixed at the same time.

Answer (score 7):

Just wanted to add that using `@blackhole` named location raised Nginx's default 500 error page when certain weird requests were sent to the server (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480528/how-to-set-nginx-uri-to-fix-empty-uri-in-redirect-to-named-location/58960429#58960429)), and thus the desired result (444) was not achieved.

I went around this by using the following notation instead:

```
error_page 301 400 403 404 500 502 503 504 =444 /444.html;
location = /444.html {
        return 444;
}
```

*Update*: note that if the above block is itself inside a `location` block, the location path `location = /444.html {…` may prompt an Nginx error upon reload because Nginx requires it be a *sub-location* of the parent `location` block --> such as: `location = [sub-location]/444.html {…`.